# problem in trying to assign a ptr to first free adressd in arm

Tags: eclipse, assembly, arm

when building this code it produces the following error:../Program4.S:11: Error: attempt to store value in absolute section

//
.data

```
.struct
   ListNode:
        value: .hword 0
        link: .quad 0
        .equ NodeSize, .-ListNode
Head: .quad 0
Nodes: .skip 100 * NodeSize
.equ OutputSize, 100
Output: .skip OutputSize * 2
FreePtr: .quad Nodes
```

.text     // program section
.globl main
.arch armv8-a+fp+simd // processor type
.type main, %function

trying to implement a linked list in armv8

im not the most knowledgeable, but i tried changing the  .skip instruction to .size, but that did not work,

Comment: That's not how you use `.struct`.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Struct.html has an example.  Especially note the *you would need to use a .section directive of some sort to change to some other section before further assembly.*, which you don't do before `Head:`